# How can this integral be $0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

Consider
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\sin x(x+\cos x)\ dx$$
Now let $$t=\cos x,\hspace{1cm}-\sin x\ dx=dt$$
and the integral becomes
$$-\int_1^1(\arccos t+t)dt$$
and this integral is obviously $0$. But this is wrong! The integral evaluates to $-2\pi$. So my substitution was not allowed, but why? Are there any restrictions on when one can apply trigonometric substitution?

Comment: The range of $\arccos$ is $[0,\pi]$. You cannot do that substitution on the whole interval of integration. That is, if $t=\cos x$, then $x=\arccos t$ only when $x$ is in $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: Basically, in substituting $x$ with $\arccos t$, you are using $x=\arccos(\cos x))$. But that is only true for $x\in [0,\pi]$. For $x$ in $[\pi,2\pi]$, you get $x=2\pi-\arccos(\cos x) = 2\pi-\arccos(t)$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I understand, thank you.

Comment: When you do substitution, not only for trig-sub, but for all substitution, you need to make sure that your substitution function is monotonic inside your integration domain. For this problem, it is not monotonic on $[0, 2\pi]$, so you get wrong answer.

Comment: Your substitution $t=\cos x$is not monotonic and hence not bijective to have its inverse. By the way, you can handle  this integral by integration by parts.

Comment: @MathFail - monotonicity is not a requirement for substitutions. Integration will take care of the turn-arounds just fine. The problem here was exactly what Arturo Magidin pointed out: The OP failed to realize their substitution did not cover the given domain of integration.

Comment: The range of $\arccos(x)$ is  $[0, \pi]$ rather than $[0, 2\pi]$ is due to the monotonicity when define the inverse function. @PaulSinclair

Comment: @MathFail - *inverse functions* exist when the function is injective, and for continuous functions on intervals, that means the function will be monotone. But that is *function inversion*, not *substitution* in an integral. Substitution does not require a monotone function. If $g$ is continuously differentiable on $[a,b]$ and $f$ is integrable between $g(a)$ and $g(b)$, then $\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)}f(u)\,du = \int_a^bf(g(x))g'(x)\,dx$ always. $g$ need not satisfy any other condition.